# How would I make this Regex expression more inclusive and accurate?

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I am using python 2.7 to find text within a paragraph of text.
the following text is part of my extraction:

```
Item 1 for Product A: Flour
Solution 1 for Product A: Water
Items 2 for Product B: Milk
Solution 2 for Product B: Oil
Item 3 for Product C: Onions

Method
```

I have the following Python code that to extract specific pieces of the information I want:

```
extract = re.findall(r"(?<=Item|s\s).*(?=\sSolution)", page_content)
```

While this extracts some of the information, I am not able to extract all that I need.
I need to include the word "Item" and I am not able to extract the last item as the next word isn't "Solution" but is Method.

my desired output would be:

```
Item 1 for Product A: Flour
Items 2 for Product B: Milk
Item 3 for Product C: Onions
```

any help would be appreciated in refining the regex.

thanks

Comment: Is there always a line break character at the end of each line?

Comment: not necessarily. actually when I convert PDF to Text using Python libraries, the output text concatenates the line breaks, so the raw text is actually:  Item 1 for Product A: FlourSolution 1 for Product A: Water etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your input looks like

```
Item 1 for Product A: FlourSolution 1 for Product A: WaterItems 2 for Product B: MilkSolution 2 for Product B: OilItem 3 for Product C: Onions

Method
```

The following pattern gives you the output you need.

```
r'(Item[s]{0,1}.*?\:\s[A-Z][a-z]*[^A-Z])'
```

Check it out here:
[https://regex101.com/r/ucPdcV/2](https://regex101.com/r/ucPdcV/1)

Comment: thanks for the response, I have adapted your expression to another query, see link: https://regex101.com/r/MySbqU/1 however I see its a bit of a hit or miss - any suggestions ?

Comment: @qbbq The pattern above can't work on the example that you have because it leverages on the capital letter as the cue to terminate. In the case that you have in the link, there are possibilities of capital-letter words sandwiched between the `:` and `Counsel`. I haven't figured a way to discriminate that properly but a quick, dirty way is to grab the whole phrase and sub `Counsel` with an empty string manually within Python

Comment: ahhh that's a great way of looking at it. thank you very much - you have helped in steering me in the right direction.